# Setting 'autoload' to 'no' with Settings API

Tags: options, settings-api

I've looked at the Settings API codex page, https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API, and I can't find anything related to setting `autoload` to `no` for any options using the Settings API.

Is there any way to achieve this using the Setttings API? Asking because I have many DB table `options` entries that were created using `register_setting` and all of the `options` have `autoload` set to `yes`.

I need to optimize this because hundreds of entries are being loaded on every page load unecessarily.

Comment: So is it autload by default? That would be actually great! Where did you find it's autoloading ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this is to add the option to the database yourself before the Settings API does so. To do this, add a 'sanitize_callback' to the register_settings function:

`register_setting ('my_options', 'my_option_name', array ('type' => 'string', 'sanitize_callback' => 'my_function_name'));`

Then, in your function, update the option yourself:

```
function my_function_name ($value) {
    update_option ('my_option_name', $value, false);
    return $value;
}
```

`

Comment: This breaks the form for me – when I submit the form, the page changes to `/wp-admin/options.php` and I get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)`. Perhaps this causes an infinite loop, where WP keeps trying to update the option.

Comment: It could only get stuck in a loop if you have other actions or filters that trigger when you update options.

Comment: Thanks @mark-barnes, I see – that's quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many possible solutions (most of them go into an infinite loop) this one is working for me.

I use the add_option_{$option} hook and then I do the following:

```
public function change_autoload_to_no( $option, $value )
{

    update_option( $option, '', 'no' );
    update_option( $option, $value, 'no' );

}
```

This might not be the most "elegant" solution but it works. I guess other option is to modify the value directly with sql.

Comment: Any reason why you run `update_option()` twice?